# pass data using putExtra and use it in onClick

Tags: android, android-studio, button, android-intent, android-activity

I wrote the following code:

```
public class HoursActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public String name;
    public String number;
    public String date;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hours);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        //if (extras != null) {
            name = extras.getString("name");
            number = extras.getString("number");
            date = extras.getString("date");
        //}
        final int hour = 9;
        //final int minute = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setId(hour);
            final int id_ = btn.getId();
            btn.setText(hour + i +":00");
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
            linearLayout.addView(btn, params);
            final Button btn1 = ((Button) findViewById(id_));
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                            date + name + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This code creates 10 buttons and I want to print the data that I get from the previous activity when I click on a button. So, I wrote the following code:

```
            name = extras.getString("name");
            number = extras.getString("number");
            date = extras.getString("date");
```

For each button I wrote this code:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                            date + name + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
```

The problem is that the string date + name + number only printed for the first button.
where did I go wrong?

Comment: You should set the on click listener on `btn`. Do away with `btn1`.

Comment: `For each button I wrote this code:` You do not have to repeat that. We saw that already.

Comment: Thank you, it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Create the intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
String getText=textView.getText().toString();

//Create the bundle
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

//Add your data to bundle
bundle.putString(“getText”, getText);

//Add the bundle to the intent
i.putExtras(bundle);

//Fire that second activity
startActivity(i);
```

and goto your second activity retrieve your data from the bundle:

```
 //Get the bundle
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    
    //Extract the data…
    String stuff = bundle.getString(“stuff”);
```